# AngularJS: ng-repeat detecting group change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a list of Cities and their Country. Each time the Country changes, I want to display the Country once. The data is already sorted so that all countries are grouped together nicely. How can I detect a change in Country in the ng-repeat so it looks like this:

```
 Canada
   Toronto
   Vancouver
 Holand
   Amsterdam
   The Hague



        <div ng-repeat="row in data.cities">
            {{row.country}}                
                 {{row.city}}
        </div>
```

Comment: Could u provide some json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.cities| groupBy: 'country'">
            {{key}}
            <div ng-repeat="row in value">
                 {{row.city}}
```

I blogged a full solution: https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2018/06/11/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-groups/